# Where do operations on models belong in Application Design Patterns?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, design-patterns, architecture, network-programming

Say we want to make an `application` containing the following:

- **Asynchronous** and **time consuming** `operations` on selected `objects`
- For a certain `object` we want to access the `status` of an associated `operation`.
- The ability to `show`, `cancel` and `pause` these operations from `multiple views`.

Then my question is the following:

#### Where do these `operations` and their `progress/status` belong in an Application Design Pattern?

To put it into context here is a dummy application:

#### Example Application:

We have an application where you can apply different `Filters` to `Images`. Application consists of a `Directory View` and `Detail View`.

- Each `filter` can be applied `asynchronously` to any `image` from each `view`.
- The `filter`-operation can be `observed` and `canceled` from both `views`.
- A filter operation can not be started if there is already one initiated for that `filter-type` and `image`, or if such a `filter` has already produced a `result`.
- In this **dummy application** the views are subsequent, but in the general case you would not be able to pass information directly between the views.

[image: Directory View]

[image]

#### Progress

Decoupling the `Service Layer` or `Network Controller` from the `View` and `Model` in a design pattern like `MVC` or `MVVM` is quite straight forward, as long as you don't provide more `UX feedback` than a `spinner` when there's an active `network request`.

But when I am working on an application confirming to the criteria above, I always end up either

- Not allowing the `user` to change `view` during an `operation`
- `Tagging` operations with the `id` of the object currently processed and passing this to the `views`, or looking in the `Network Controller` directly from the `views/view controllers`
- Creating a separate `entities` for `operations`, and suddenly I have a `request operation` in my `model`

So obviously there are (*very smelly*) ways to come around this, but they all feel dirty and not inline with how the patterns are intended.

So purely from a **software architecture** and **design pattern** point of view, how would you approaching this?

Answer (score 2):

I generally prefer a promise object for this design issue.  The promise object can contain methods to cancel the operation, check on the status of the operation and even contain closures to be executed depending on what happens with the operation (success, failure, cancel, etc.).

That promise object can either be handed from view to view or can be served from the network layer upon multiple requests (view A kicks off operation, view B tries later to kick it off but it is already running so gets the same promise object).

> That means that the service layer, or network layer in this case, needs to present which operations, requests, are ongoing for which object, right? Because you don't want to kick of a request just to get the promise object, in case a button should be hidden if the operation is already started. I guess you would keep these promise objects outside your app model since they don't live between sessions, and the network layer would store them by url, but how would you generally serve this back from the network layer without exposing to much the network layer to the ui?

Network layer has convenience methods for the UI to utilize to kick off requests that the user initiates.  The network layer determines if a request has already started and returns the same promise.  Even if the network layer kicked off the process internally (auto refresh, etc) it can still deliver the promise back to the UI if the UI tries to start the same process.

The promise objects only live as long as the operation is on-going.  I actually have the operation be the true holder of the promise object and the network controller holds the queue of operations.  Then when a request comes in, I search the queue for the existence of that operation and if it exists return the promise from the operation.  If it doesn't exist, I create a new operation, put it in the queue and return its promise object.

The interface between the UI and the back end is the exposed methods on the network controller.  The UI has no knowledge of operations, it just has a function that says "go refresh this or go get that" and gets a promise back.  It does not need to know or care how the job is performed, it just knows that the promise is its way to check on the status of that operation.

Now, if it is a data refresh, then the promise isn't needed for data updates, the `NSFetchedResultsController` will handle that.  The promise in that situation handles "am I active" and "cancel me" type requests only.

Answer (score 0):

There will be many ways to do this. But here's an idea... Maybe you can use [messaging](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessagingComponentsIntro.html) as style: define a "status" channel, possibly use a pub-sub model for getting the status/progress of on-going operations. So that way, the process performing the operations publishes the status on a channel, and your multiple views subscribe to that channel and display the status. Now, if you have to cancel/pause operations, you possibly need to have another control channel. You do have to manage concurrency, order etc.

Comment: Messaging would be one way to do it indeed. Now looking at my question again after your answer, I realise that I need to reformulate myself a bit. But what the real problem boils down to how to check if a certain process is active for a certain object when a new view is presented. I will reformulate my question tomorrow and add an example. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: Yes, now you got me thinking. So every time a process activates, it needs to store/publish some state - progress/status whatever info you need from it. Updating it's state could be the responsibility of the process, it is a matter of design. But once your process' state is published, displaying it in multiple views shouldn't be a problem. Now, managing a control channel is more complicated, because you are changing your active process' state. Again to manage concurrency, ordering etc, you will have to design well.  I think this is a good start. You will get there! Good luck!

Comment: You certainly need some good design, that's why its a design question! =) Thanks for you input, if you think of something more please let me know!